# Average function on a group by shows wrong number for TSQL query

Tags: t-sql, group-by

I have used the below query:

```
select format(CreatedOn, 'yyyy', 'fa') as Date, 
       sum((elg_Behaviour-861239999)) as Sum,
       count(*) as Count, 
       AVG((elg_Behaviour-861239999)) as Average 
  from elg_surveyBase  
 group by format(CreatedOn, 'yyyy', 'fa')
```

The requirement is to show the average grouped by column 1, but avg is always 1.

| Date | Sum | Count | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1400 | 24 | 20 | 1 |
| 1401 | 69 | 51 | 1 |
| 1402 | 26 | 19 | 1 |

It should be 24/20= 1.2 or 69/51=1.35

Comment: We will need some example data which clearly shows the issue you're having. A good way to provide it is: `DECLARE @Table TABLE (Col1 INT, Col2 INT, ...); INSERT INTO @Table (Co1, Col2,...) VALUES (1, 1,...), (2, 2,...)...;`

Comment: I'd *guess* that `elg_Behaviour` is an `int`? The `AVG` of an `int` will be an `int`; if you don't want an `int`, then `CONVERT`/`CAST` the value *before* you average it. Or, as you are subtracting `861239999` from the value, make that value a numeric: `861239999.`

Comment: It's difficult (or impossible) to be able to answer this accurately without some sample data and expected results. Check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, converting to a decimal type with some precision should give you decimal results for the average:

```
select 
    format(CreatedOn, 'yyyy', 'fa') as Date, 
    sum((elg_Behaviour-861239999)) as Sum,
    count(*) as Count, 
    avg((convert(decimal(10,2),elg_Behaviour)-861239999)) as Average 
 from elg_surveyBase  
 group by format(CreatedOn, 'yyyy', 'fa')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably wanting something like this

```
SELECT
    FORMAT(CreatedOn, 'yyyy', 'fa') AS Date,
    SUM(elg_Behaviour - 861239999) AS Sum,
    COUNT(*) AS Count,
    AVG(CAST(elg_Behaviour AS FLOAT) - 861239999) AS Average
FROM elg_surveyBase
GROUP BY FORMAT(CreatedOn, 'yyyy', 'fa')
```